# Artifacts after corner rounding, pywin32

Tags: python-3.x, winapi, kivy, gdi+, pywin32

I have minimal code in `python kivy + pywin32`. I use the `CreateRoundRectRgn` function to create a region with rounded corners, and then assign this region to my window via `SetWindowRgn`. How to remove artifacts on corners?

[Here are the artifacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9ci7.png)

```py
import os
import win32con
import win32gui
import win32api

os.environ['PYTHONFAULTHANDLER'] = '1'

from additive import createDirs, writer

createDirs(["config",], True)
writer(0, 1)

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, FadeTransition
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

def resource_path(relative_path):
    try:
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

TemplateDir = resource_path('styles/')
for file in os.listdir(TemplateDir):
    Builder.load_file(TemplateDir+file)

from LocalScreen import LocalScreen as LS

from userWidgets import TB

class FastMessageApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FastMessageApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        Window.clearcolor = (0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1)
        Window.size = (500, 400)
        Window.set_title("FastMessage")

        self.HWND = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "FastMessage")
        self.RoundedRegion = win32gui.CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0, 500, 400, 50, 50)
        win32gui.SetWindowRgn(self.HWND, self.RoundedRegion, True)
        win32gui.SetWindowLong(self.HWND, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE, win32gui.GetWindowLong(self.HWND, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE) | win32con.WS_EX_LAYERED)
        win32gui.SetLayeredWindowAttributes(self.HWND, win32api.RGB(0,0,0), 255, win32con.LWA_ALPHA)

        self.__Manager = ScreenManager(transition = FadeTransition(duration=0.1), size_hint = (1,0.95), pos_hint = {'bottom': 1})

    def build(self):
        self.__Window = FloatLayout()
        self.__Window.add_widget(TB())
        self.__Window.add_widget(self.__Manager)
        return self.__Window

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = FastMessageApp()
    app.run()
```

I tried to reduce the radius of the rounding, but the size of the artifacts remained the same, although there were fewer of them.

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPgpC.png)

I also tried to call the `ExtSelectClipRgn` function from `GDI` via `ctypes`, but none of the flags helped me.

Comment: You can't. The window region is binary: A pixel is either inside or outside. If you want alpha-blended smoothing, use a [layered window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#layered-windows).

Comment: Please, could you give an example based on my code, I would be grateful for your help?